# Samba replacement for Linux and Windows

Tags: linux, windows, performance, samba, network-share

I have a lot of machines (Windows and Linux) and one samba server.

I want to improve samba performance. How I should do this? I need a distributed file system, preferably Open Source. :)

I use glusterFS and it's very good, because I need a solution that works on Windows too, not only Unix.

Comment: Seconding SvenW's commentary - explain your problem more fully. \

Answer (score 1):

You don't us tell anything about your problems. Please enhance your question with the following:

- Why do you want to replace Samba?
- What are your requirements?
- What is your current hardware and your budget?
- Do you want your solution free as in beer or free as in speech?
- AFAIK GlusterFS doesn't work on Windows, but need a Samba share export. What do you mean?

Anyway, something to look into:

- Clustered Samba
- Faster servers
- DFS shares with Samba

Comment: I want to replace Samba because I read and save large amount of data and it's slowly.
I require very fast and scallable solution for Windows and Linux.

Comment: So, esio, what have you done to prove that the problem is the Samba software itself, as opposed to an IO bottleneck on your storage controller (for example) ?

Answer (score 1):

> because I need solution that works on Windows too

Either you've not explained your problem very well or you don't understand the difference between the file sharing protocol and the disk filesystem.

In principle you could set up a cluster of Linux boxes using glusterFS for the storage, Samba for file service and a load balancer between the cluster and the MSWindows clients. If you decide to go down this route, your life will be a lot simpler if you use [CTDB](http://ctdb.samba.org/). Or you could use [Samba's own clustering solution](http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Clustered_Samba) (although I'm not sure hoow stable this is).

If, on the other hand, you require to have MSWindows boxes acting as servers then certainly this isn't going to work - in which case have a look at [AFS](http://www.openafs.org/).

Comment: Windows as an AFS server is unsupported. http://docs.openafs.org/ReleaseNotesWindows/ch03s11.html